# Dataframe dominant stats analysis using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that has several columns. The values in one of the columns is a percentage that sums up to 1, say Column A. I want to print the values in another column, Column B, such that these correspond to the largest values in Column A that sum up to 0.95.

Eg:

```
Column A        Column B
   A1             0.2
   A2             0.5
   A3             0.25
   A4             0.01
   A5             0.03
   A6             0.01
```

The result should be

```
    A1
    A2 
    A3
```

as the corresponding values of these values in Column B sum up to 0.95

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post what you attempted as this looks like a request for code and SO does not operate like this

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `cumsum` with boolean indexing using `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Column B'].cumsum() <= .95,'Column A']
```

Edit:  As hausdork points out if we want to do it with the largest values then we could `sort_values`:

```
df.loc[df.sort_values(by='Column B', ascending=False)['Column B'].cumsum() <= .95,'Column A']
```

Output:

```
0    A1
1    A2
2    A3
Name: Column A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Don't we need to sort the dataframe by Column B first? Since the OP asked for the largest values of Column A that sum to be less than .95.

Comment: Thanks very much. This is very useful. One additional comment is is there any way to prevent the listing of line numbers, Name and dtype. I tried copying this to an array and used list() command. This works but is there a better method ?